# Java PrintWriter output looks weird in notepad

Tags: java, printf

When I look at the file using mousepad on Linux, it looks correct. When I look at the file on Windows XP or Windows 7 with notepad, the output is all on the same line and is incorrect.

Here is the (correct) output for out.txt I'm getting on Linux:

```
  3.40        4.50        5.60
  3.40        4.50        5.60
  3.40        4.50        5.60
```

EDIT: I encoded the text with CR+LF and it looks right, but how do I get java to export in that fashion?

Here's the code, it's just for testing this.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class untitled {

    public static void main (String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {      

        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("out.txt");

        double number1 = 3.4;
        double number2 = 4.5;
        double number3 = 5.6;

        for (int x=0; x<3; x++) {
        output.printf("%6.2f",number1);
        output.printf("%12.2f",number2);
        output.printf("%12.2f",number3);
        output.println("");
        }

        output.close();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: See this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline. The newline standards are different between Linux and Windows.

Comment: Notepad is the worst tool to see text file and sometimes ignores tabs/newlines. Try opening the file in a another text editor such as Editplus(commercial) or Notepad++/Crimson Editor. It should display just fine.

Comment: run your code in windows and see the output

Comment: Hi all, I have to use notepad for school :(. Mystical, I did LF+CR and it looks right in Windows, how do I tell Java to export in that format though? That's the important thing.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a "standard" way to do it in Java. (hence why I didn't post it an answer) But I suppose `output.print("\r\n")` will work. I can make this an answer if you want.

Comment: That makes sense, I guess my final question is. If compiled in windows, it will look right in notepad right? THanks so much for your time.

Comment: If you *run* it in Windows it should be correct. (I don't think it matters where you compile it though.) Someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: *Everything* looks weird in Notepad :-|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it looks "weird" is because the Windows convention/standard for separating lines is Carriage Return, Line Feed (`"\r\n"`), as opposed to the *nix way of just a line feed (`"\n"`). Therefore if you use a basic editor such as notepad, everything will seem to be on the same line. Better editors such as Notepad++, or even wordpad, will display the text file properly even if it's in *nix format.

If you run your Java program in Windows, the line separators will be set appropriately, however you can also change the line separator explicitly so that it is always `"\r\n"` by using [System.setProperty()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) with the `"line.separator"` key.

Comment: I should note that I compile it in linux and took the output file that was made in linux, emailed it to myself and looked at it on windows... if I were to simply compile it on windows, would it look right? Thanks for the comment, that makes somewhat sense to me, this is a new concept

Comment: @user1062058: On Linux the `"line.separator"` key will be set to `"\n"` and on Windows it'll be `"\r\n"`. So yeah, if you run your program on Windows, the output will look *"right"*.

Answer (score 2):

If you do printf("%n"); Java will print the appropriate line separator for your platform.