# create a text file from String Array

Tags: java, android, file

```
    String strFileContent="";    
    Log.e(TAG, "Error loading image file names333");
    StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();///

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        ///strFileContent += ""+x[i]+",";
        contents.append(x[i]);///
    contents.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));///
    }
    strFileContent=contents.toString();///
```

```
String file = "scores8";
```

java or android:
how create a text file from String array x[] one element in each line??? what type of file to use no ext or txt or...???

Comment: You are building a String with the content you need. Are you asking how to write that to a file? (And your search engine is broken ;)  The choice of extension is up to you but `.txt` is often used for text.

Comment: You could try [FileUtils.writeLines()](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/package-summary.html) from Apache Commons IO for a one-liner solution.

Comment: in eclipse file appear as wanted one array item per line but in notepad appear in one line concatenated.... what the problem with notepad... ? this is considered notepad problem?

Comment: @user1638936 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336428/java-printwriter-output-looks-weird-in-notepad

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] array = {...};
File file = new File("FilePath");
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file, true);
for(String s : array) pw.println(s);
pw.close();
```

Comment: in eclipse file appear as wanted one array item per line but in notepad appear in one line concatenated.... what the problem with notepad... ? this is considered notepad problem?

Comment: @user1638936 Yes, Notepad is windows application which uses `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeLines%28java.io.File,%20java.util.Collection%29) in Apache Commons IO:

```
FileUtils.writeLines(new File("file.txt"), Arrays.asList(array));
```